# I want to insert unique value in my MVC using Entity Framework.I have looked all the answer available in stackoverflow, But still i cant get.

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please some one provide me complete tutorial to insert only unique value in database.If any duplicate data is tried to insert it should show error message. 
please provide me complete tutorials because i am beginner

Comment: Better try and then ask the question would help you better

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ

```
Your_Context_DB context = new Your_Context_DB();
public bool function(Your_entity entity)
{
    if(context.Entity.Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).Count() > 0) {
        return true; //The value has been existed.
    }
    else
        return false; //The value has not been existed.
}
```